# Rewrite url query string to look like directory

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting

Well, I am not good in English actually so I couldn't explain my problem shortly in the title...

Shortly, I need to make

```
http://<SITE>/user/?id=<x>
```

to

```
http://<SITE>/id<x>
```

Is it possible in Microsoft Azure using web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your web.config you should insert inside `<system.webServer>` section this rules:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect for user" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^user" /> 
          <conditions>
             <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=(\d+)" />  
          </conditions>  
          <action type="Redirect" url="/id/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It will redirect urls like that `http://<SITE>/user/?id=<x>` into `http://<SITE>/id<x>` where `<x>` is digits